# How to logout of android app after particular time?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an android app which has a login and logout option. How do I make the app go back to login screen if the user has logged in and not used it(or kept idle) for some time(say 10min)? Also, how do I check for multiple logins? Please note that my app uses an external database(mysql). I did this using php code. Also, how do I check for multiple logins(I've multiple users) from mysql and allow each user to log in?

This is my code for authentication:

```
try
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/user_validate.php");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

    byte[] data = new byte[256];

    buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int len = 0;
    while (-1 != (len = inputStream.read(data)) )
    {
        buffer.append(new String(data, 0, len));
    }

    inputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "error"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

if(buffer.charAt(0)=='Y')
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
        Home.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: The alarm manager may be of use - http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: Are you using xml for authentication in android.

Comment: @Newts i've updated my question. Please check out now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the app or on the server you want to store the timestamp of the last successfully completed user action (that requires login credentials).

Then test against that timestamp to see if the current request is more or less than the 10 min threshold. If its longer than 10 mins after the last successful timestamp then you need to get the user to log in again.

Comment: can u please tell me how to implement this?

Comment: you're going to have to do some of this yourself. when you make a call to an api that requires the user to log in you need to check to see if you have a timestamp saved, and if the current timestamp minus the saved timestamp is greater than 10 mins (or 600 seconds). You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html to store timestamps (or store it in mysql database on the server)

Comment: No, I've given you the keywords to conduct your own research, and told you how to do it. Now you need to go away and do what I've told you. I assume you've created what you have of the app to date? If so then you must have the ability to put what I've said into motion? Unfortunately I can't write your app for you.